# MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rakesh'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-20.04

While running MySQL in Ubuntu 20.04 terminal, I run into the following error:

> MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rakesh'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

try using mysql with root, afterwards use the following commands :

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

You will see all he available users there . Then, try

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yournewpassword';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a mysql account created. sudo to root, then run mysql, it will let you in. Then create yourself an account and a database using the `GRANT` command:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: can you share your guided version this documentation is quite confusing

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE rakesh; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON rakesh.* to rakesh@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';`

Comment: @Gordon Bobic not working,i've been stuck there since 3 days